# bower ENOTFOUND Package App States=bower.json not found

Tags: angularjs, npm, bower, bower-install

How can I fix the following problem?

```
aaa@aaa $ bower install bower.json

bower bower.json#*              cached git://github.com/Kalitte/app-states.git#0.6.9
bower bower.json#*            validate 0.6.9 against git://github.com/Kalitte/app-states.git#*
bower webcomponentsjs#~0.5.4    cached git://github.com/Polymer/webcomponentsjs.git#0.5.5
bower webcomponentsjs#~0.5.4  validate 0.5.5 against git://github.com/Polymer/webcomponentsjs.git#~0.5.4
bower                        ENOTFOUND Package App States=bower.json not found
```

> bower                        ENOTFOUND Package App States=bower.json
>   not found

Comment: It may have a problem with the new version of bower?

Comment: just  type bower install.

Comment: it is still not working

Comment: I opened new project and install bower again, and problem is gone. what a silly solution, but works :)

Comment: Thanks @Celik. That worked :) Didn't expect it to be so simple

Answer (score 36):

I don't know how or at what point this happened, but it happened to me and if you look inside your `bower_components` folder there maybe a folder called `App States`. I deleted this folder and I was able to do an install.

Comment: This should be accepted answer. It happened to me when I copied an entire bower_components from Windows to Linux

Answer (score 4):

You have your bower config in bower.json file, right? You don't give the file as argument, it messes like you show.

So, type in the folder that holds the bower.json file only

```
bower install
```

That command will find the bower.json for you automatically.

Comment: when I type  only "bower install", it still gives the same error

Comment: I opened new project and install bower again, and problem is gone. what a silly solution, but works :)

Comment: Maybe you post this as answer and then accept it? That way you can get question in answered mode.

Comment: It happens that exists a bugged bower module also called "bower.json" (https://libraries.io/bower/bower.json) so if you accidentally type "bower install bower.json" instead of "bower install", it starts installing the "bower.json" module from internet which messes all up, and makes the following "bower install" commands to fail with the OP message. So **the solution is to remove the whole bower_components folder first** and then regenerate it again cleanly with "bower install" as mico says.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the bower had created  "App States" folder and after deleting the folder the error got resolved. 
After deleting the folder: execute

`bower install --allow-root`

This should fix the issue.